# IsDouble() in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Is there any IsDouble() function in VB6? If I'm not mistaken, Double data type in VB6 is equivalent to float in SQL Server 2000.
Your advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Function IsDouble(ByVal varValue As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim dblTest As Double
   On Error Resume Next
   dblTest = CDbl(varValue)
   IsDouble = Err.Number = 0 
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your codes. 
Let me reveal the background, I need to check a string value which comes from a text file in order to insert into a field (SQL float datatype) of a database table (SQL Server 2000).

Comment: Be careful what CDbl will accept as input though.  I think it accepts trailing nonsense characters.

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking of the Val function.  But if you have international users you might want to test this against those too.  I think CDBl uses the regional settings to do the conversion.

Comment: I don't think VB handles boolean expressions like that.

Comment: You can put parenthesis around it or call the CBool function if you really want to.  But the above works.

Comment: Hmm... I know I have old code where I wanted to build a bool that way and wasn't able to.  So I dug back (waaay back!) and found an example, and it turns out the reason was 'company policy' at my then work place.  Old habits die hard, I guess.

Comment: This would work if "IsDouble" means "is varValue able to be expressed as a double".  It will not work if it means "is the type of varValue double", because it will also accept integer, long, currency and single types and return true.  Goes to show you that most of the failures in application development have to do with incorrectly gathered requirements rather than incorrect execution.

Answer (score 10):

Actually you are much better off using the Vartype function.

```
Private Function IsDouble(ByVal value As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDouble = (VarType(value) = vbDouble)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

IsNumeric() is fine, it will only accept values that fit into Doubles. It is regionally aware, i.e. for French regional settings the decimal separator is a comma.

I just tried this in the Immediate window.

```
Debug.Print IsNumeric("4e308") 
False
```

The definition of a VB6 Double in the manual is "VB6 Double variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers ranging in value from -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values and from 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive values".

I think that's the same as a SQL Server float, going by the online [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271.aspx). "Floating precision number data with the following valid values: -1.79E + 308 through -2.23E - 308, 0 and 2.23E + 308 through 1.79E + 308."

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt **IsDouble** function available in VB6 instead you can use inbuilt **IsNumeric** Function. Otherwise you can use following User Defined Function to achieve the same:

```
Function IsDouble(ByVal value As Variant) As Boolean

   Dim convertedValue As Double

On Error Goto EH
   convertedValue = CDbl(value)
   IsDouble = True

Exit Function
   EH:
        IsDouble = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an `IsNumeric()` function that should work well enough.  If that is inadequate for your needs can you also explain in what ways?

Comment: Let me reveal the background, I need to check a string value which comes from a text file in order to insert into a field (SQL float datatype) of a database table (SQL Server 2000).

Comment: Okay.  The only problem with IsNumeric then is that it would allow an overflow: a number that is too big to fit in a float type.

Comment: That's not correct, it will only accept values that fit into a Double. (IEEE standard 8 byte floating point number)

Comment: MarkJ ... Do you mean that whichever value that satisfies IsNumeric() will not always overflow SQL 2K float data type? Am I right to say that?

Comment: I think so - I'm not that familiar with SQL server. "VB6 Double variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers ranging in value from -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values and from 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive values"

Comment: Googling "t-sql float" reveals this as the size, for those interested:  

- 1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308.  Number of bytes varies from 4 to 8 depending on the specified precision in scientific notation (which in t-sql can be specified): float(24) or less is 4 bytes, larger is 8.  float without a size defaults to float(53), the largest allowable value.